# Fermat's Little Theorem Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can we use Fermat's Little Theorm to find the least non-negative residue modulo m with numbers with large exponents. For example, how would one find the least non-negative residue modulo m with values $n = 3^{1000000}$ and $m = 19$.

I understand how the basic method works (ie finding a way to introduce a factor of $3^{18}$ and then reducing), but dividing 1000000 by 18 is time consuming and I feel there is a quicker method that I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, finding the remainder of $10^6$ by $18$ is not really that tough

Observe that $10^{n+1}-10=10(10^n-1)$ is divisible by $10\cdot 9=90,$  as $9\mid(10^n-1)$ for $n\ge1$

Hence $18\mid(10^{n+1}-10)\implies 10^{n+1}\equiv10\pmod{18}$ for $n\ge1$

So, $$3^{10^n}\equiv3^{10}\pmod {19} \text{ for } n\ge1$$

Comment: As $(a-b)\mid(a^n-b^n)$ where $a,b,n$ are positive integers, $(10-1)\mid(10^n-1)$

Comment: How did you jump from mod 18 to mod 19, that's the step I don't really understand.

Comment: @Ockham, for prime $p$ and $(x,p)=1,$ if $a\equiv b\pmod {p-1},$ i.e., $a=c(p-1)+b$ for some integer $c, x^a=x^{c(p-1)+b}=(x^{p-1})^c\cdot x^b\equiv x^b\pmod p$ as $x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here that has caused the down vote

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{18}\equiv 1 \text{ mod 19}$$
$$3^{18*55555}\equiv 1 \text{ mod 19}$$
$$3^{999990}\equiv 1\text{ mod 19}$$
$$3^{1000000}\equiv 3^{10} \text{ mod 19}$$
$$3^{1000000}\equiv 16\text{ mod 19}$$

Comment: can you explain a little more about what you did at each step?

Comment: $a^b\equiv c\implies (a^b)^d\equiv c^d \implies a^{bd}\equiv c^d,$ not $a^{b^d}\equiv c^d$

Comment: So the steps listed above are not correct?

Comment: I don't think this result is correct. According to wolfram alpha $3^{10^6} \equiv 7 \space \text{mod} \space 19$ does not hold.

Comment: @Ockham I fixed it, sorry for errors.

Comment: Was there any special way you determined the factor 55555 or was it just trial and error?

Comment: @Ockham Trial and error, I recommend lab bhattacharjee's idea

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 9\!:\, 10^6\equiv 1^6\equiv  1,\,\ mod\ 2\!:\, 10^6\equiv 0,\ $ so $\rm\ mod\ 18\!:\, 10^6\equiv 10,\,$ so $\rm\,mod\ 19\!:\ 3^{10^6}\!\equiv 3^{10}$

**Alternatively** $ $ we may employ [Euler's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [quadratic reciprocity:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)

$$\rm\quad mod\ 19\!:\,\ \color{#C00}{3^9} \equiv \left(\frac{3}{19}\right) \equiv\, -\left(\frac{19}{3}\right)\equiv\, -\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\equiv\,\color{#C00}{-1}$$

$\rm 10^6\!-1 = 9k,\ k\ odd,\,$ so $\rm\, mod\ 19\!:\ 3^{10^6} = 3^{1+9k} =\, 3 (\color{#C00}{3^9})^k\equiv 3 (\color{#C00}{-1})^k\equiv -3$

Comment: I assume your using some theorem that allows you to multiply mod values, can you tell me the name of the theorem or give a little explanation as to how  this whole thing works

Comment: $\rm mod\ 9\!: 10^6\equiv 1,\:$ so $\rm\:mod\ 18\!: 10^6\equiv 1\ \ or\ \ 1+9=10.\:$ Since $\rm\,10^6\,$ is even, it must be $10.\:$ Generally one can use CRT (Chinese Remainder), but that'd be overkill here.

Comment: @MathGems It was overkill once you started adding colors lol

Comment: @Ethan The colors greatly aid the reader to follow the structure of the inferences. E.g. when I wrote equational inferences like above in older systems without such highlight capabilities, I often received questions, e.g. why is the penultimate congruence true? With it and its source both highlighted in red, one easily sees that it is an application of the [replacement rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2861/23500) $\rm\: a\equiv b\:\Rightarrow\:f(a)\equiv f(b),\:$ where $\rm\:f(n) = 3n^k,\:$ and $\rm\,a= 3^9,\,b= -1.\ \ $ In more complex proofs, this structure may be much less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Modular arithmetic makes this easy.

To find 1000000 modulo 18, we can first find 100000 modulo 18, and then multiply by 10 and reduce modulo 18 again.

To find 100000 modulo 18, we can first find 10000 modulo 18, and then multiply by 10 and reduce modulo 18 again.

To find 10000 modulo 18....